# How can I make a sprite move downward in a 2D space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to make a game object in unity just go vertically down.

I have tried using `GameObject.transform()` and things like that. All I am asking is, if anyone can give me something to look into such as which method or class I would use to make a 2D sprite move downward.

Comment: Post the current code you have that is not working then I will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, you can modify the position of any object using it's `transform` component and it's `position` property. For example, if you have `GameObject someSprite`, you can assign a new value to `someSprite.transform.position` every frame. Usually it is done in your `Update` method, or, if you're working with physics, in the `FixedUpdate` method.